# Uncertain about Schengen visa application question about residency type

Tags: schengen, ireland, residency, minors

I'm on a critical skill permit in Ireland. My son and wife are also with me as dependents. We are registered with GNIB (Garda National Immigration Bureau) cards and have our multi-entry visa.

While filling in the Schengen visa application form, in column 18, it says to write residency permit type, the number, and validity. What should I write here?

Is it okay for me and my wife to put our GNIB details here? What do we put for my son, since he never received a GNIB? Am I supposed to write the multi-entry visa details for my child?

Answer (score 1):

Your GNIB card is your [Irish Residence Permit](http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/about-registration-system)

> NOTE: From 11 December 2017 the new Irish Residence Permit (IRP) has replaced the 'GNIB card'. Do not apply for an IRP until your current GNIB card expires.

As children younger than 15 do not register, use your child’s long-stay visa details, as it is the permission to remain in, and return to, Ireland.